# Memory leaks with "Multi-Threaded Debug" (/MTd) and no leaks with "Multi-Threaded Debug DLL" (/MDd)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks

I have a bunch of libraries and projects in a solution that I changed to using /MTd instead of /MDd. I'm using VS2008.

I suddenly get a whole bunch of memory leaks that did not exist with the /MDd switch.

Using [Visual Leak Detector](https://vld.codeplex.com/), I noticed that all the leaks are internal to various libraries, including CRT, VS libraries and boost.

For example, here the call-stacks of the first 3 leaks (the project is a Boost::Test project):

```
---------- Block 1 at 0x02211EA0: 568 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\tidtable.c (395): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!_mtinit + 0x18 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (215): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x5 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (182): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x7C817077 (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!RegisterWaitForInputIdle + 0x49 bytes
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    F0 20 21 02    0C 9D B8 00    8A 01 00 00     ......!. ........
    14 02 00 00    02 00 00 00    01 00 00 00    FD FD FD FD     ........ ........
    84 1B 00 00    FF FF FF FF    22 00 00 00    02 00 00 00     ........ ".......
    00 00 00 00    C5 03 8A E6    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    B0 80 8C 03    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    E8 C9 B8 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    B0 4A 21 02    F8 DB C4 00     ........ .J!.....
    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    D0 57 99 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     .W...... ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    43 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ C.......
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


---------- Block 2 at 0x022120F0: 2084 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\ioinit.c (137): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!_ioinit + 0x15 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (235): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x5 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (182): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x7C817077 (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!RegisterWaitForInputIdle + 0x49 bytes
  Data:
    A0 1E 21 02    90 4A 21 02    A4 C4 B8 00    88 00 00 00     ..!..J!. ........
    00 08 00 00    02 00 00 00    02 00 00 00    FD FD FD FD     ........ ........
    03 00 00 00    C1 0A 00 00    01 00 00 00    00 F8 15 00     ........ ........
    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    A0 0F 00 00    00 0A 0A 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    07 00 00 00    C1 0A 00 00    01 00 00 00    38 F8 15 00     ........ ....8...
    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    A0 0F 00 00    00 0A 0A 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    0B 00 00 00    C1 0A 00 00    01 00 00 00    70 F8 15 00     ........ ....p...
    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    A0 0F 00 00    00 0A 0A 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    FF FF FF FF    00 0A 00 00    01 00 00 00    D8 FF 15 00     ........ ........
    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


---------- Block 118 at 0x02212FC0: 60 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\mlock.c (279): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!_mtinitlocknum + 0x13 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\langapi\undname\undname.cxx (649): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!__unDName + 0x7 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\typname.cpp (124): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!type_info::_Name_base + 0x1F bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\typinfo.cpp (45): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!type_info::name + 0xD bytes
    c:\...\3rdpartylibs\boost_1_49_0\boost\test\unit_test_suite_impl.hpp (377): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!boost::unit_test::ut_detail::generate_test_case_4_type<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::template_test_case_gen<Bitset_b85_Serialization_Tests::deserialize_from_empty_string_should_fail_invoker,boost::mpl::vector_c<int,5,59,519,1021,1024,1025,1026,3021,7024,11 + 0xF bytes
    c:\...\3rdpartylibs\boost_1_49_0\boost\mpl\for_each.hpp (79): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!boost::mpl::aux::for_each_impl<0>::execute<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector11<boost::mpl::integral_c<int,5>,boost::mpl::integral_c<int,59>,boost::mpl::integral_c<int,519>,boost::mpl::integral_c<int,1021>,boost::mpl::integral_c<int,1024>,boost::mpl::i
    c:\...\3rdpartylibs\boost_1_49_0\boost\mpl\for_each.hpp (101): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!boost::mpl::for_each<boost::mpl::vector_c<int,5,59,519,1021,1024,1025,1026,3021,7024,11025,22026,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647>,boost::mpl::make_identity<boost::mpl::arg<-1> >,boost::uni + 0x21 bytes
    c:...\3rdpartylibs\boost_1_49_0\boost\test\unit_test_suite_impl.hpp (405): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!boost::unit_test::ut_detail::template_test_case_gen<Bitset_b85_Serialization_Tests::deserialize_from_empty_string_should_fail_invoker,boost::mpl::vector_c<int,5,59,519,1021,1024,1025,1026,3021,7024,11025,22026,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2 + 0x35 bytes
    c:\...\src\bitset_serialization_test.cpp (31): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!Bitset_b85_Serialization_Tests::`dynamic initializer for 'deserialize_from_empty_string_should_fail_registrar31'' + 0x5D bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (903): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!_initterm
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (307): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!_cinit + 0xF bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (249): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x7 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (182): FrameworkUnitTests.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x7C817077 (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!RegisterWaitForInputIdle + 0x49 bytes
  Data:
    90 4A 21 02    78 40 21 02    5C 9B B8 00    17 01 00 00     .J!.x@!. \.......
    18 00 00 00    02 00 00 00    76 00 00 00    FD FD FD FD     ........ v.......
    F8 F9 15 00    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    A0 0F 00 00    FD FD FD FD                    ........ ........
```

Does anybody know what's going on?

**EDIT:**
From what I understand, the difference between the 2 switches/modes is whether or not two linked DLLs will share the same CRT (e.g. memory management) or each have its own. When each uses its own (/MT[d]) then one cannot release resources allocated by the other.
However, I link everything statically, so there are no DLLs involved, at least not in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing similar things, I have the idea that it might just be a one-time initialization thing:

```
---------- Block 119 at 0x007B6AF8: 60 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\mlock.c (276): _mtinitlocknum
f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\stream.c (72): _getstream
f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fopen.c (61): _fsopen
f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fopen.c (125): fopen
```

If _mtinitlocknum() allocates a buffer that is subsequently used, this might be a false positive. In other words, it re-uses the buffer after that.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing. The following code snippet illustrates. If you watch the Visual Studio memory usage it creeps up steadily for MTd but remains steady with MDd. It's as though the fclose() isn't doing anything. I have proved that return values are all good via assert statements.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

while (1) 
{
    FILE* fh = fopen("c:\\temp\\1.txt", "a");
    if (fh != NULL)
    {
        int fc = fclose(fh);
    }
}
return (0);

} // WinMain
```